# filesystem::* strange results in windows filesystem paths with extended chars

Tags: c++, encoding, filesystems

Code doesn't do anything useful. It's just try & error code to figure out what's going on:

```
fs::path path("e:\\Σtest");
cout<<path << " exsits="<< fs::exists(path) << " is dir=" << fs::is_directory(path) << std::endl;

fs::path pathL(L"e:\\Σtest");
cout<<pathL << " exsits="<< fs::exists(pathL) << " is dir=" << fs::is_directory(pathL) << std::endl;

fs::path pathu(u"e:\\Σtest");
cout<<pathu << " exsits="<< fs::exists(pathu) << " is dir=" << fs::is_directory(pathu) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
e:\Σtest exsits=0 is dir=0
e:\Σtest exsits=0 is dir=0
e:\Σtest exsits=0 is dir=0
```

I sure that folder `Σtest` exists. I guess there is encoding involve somehow. I can't figure out what sophisticated problem we have encounter here, someone can explain output?

EDIT:
Following @cpplearner advice to pass `/utf-8` to compiler output changes (also code page for console was changed to utf-8 by `chcp 65001`):

```
e:\Σtest exsits=0 is dir=0
e:\?test exsits=1 is dir=1
e:\?test exsits=1 is dir=1
```

Question remain the same, what magic happen here?

Comment: What encoding is your source file using?

Comment: My source file is using: UTF-8.

Comment: Pass `/utf-8` to the compiler?

Comment: @cpplearner your advice fix the problem :D. Can you explain why? I will accept answer with explanation of this phenomenon.